# Pretty way to return one or multiple values from interface method

Tags: java

I have the following interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Mapper<I, O> {
   Collection<O> map(I in);
}
```

And this is planned to be used like this:

```
class Writer<E> {

   private final Iterator<?> it;
   private final Mapper<?, E> mapper;
   private final Output<E> out;

   public <T> Writer(Iterator<T> it, Mapper<T, E> mapper, Output<E> out) {
      this.it = it;
      this.mapper = mapper;
      this.out = out;
   }

   void write() {
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         Collection<E> items = mapper.map(it.next());
         for (E item : items) {
            out.write(item);
         }
      }
   }

}
```

The problem is users of the Writer class have to box every mapped value to a collection, even if they want to return one value. For example:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Writer<String> writer = new Writer<>(
   strings.iterator(),
   str -> Collections.singletonList(str),
   new FileOutput(...));
```

The user has to write `str -> Collections.singletonList(str)` instead of `Function.identity()` (or, for example, a constructor reference `StringHolder::new`)

Are there any ideas on how to simplify this approach or is this problem is just contrived?

Thanks!

Comment: Propose another class/constructor for when they want to use single values rather than collections. Investigate if factory methods wouldn't make your stuff easier to use than telling the users to call constructors directly.

Comment: Also, since each instance of Writer is rather obviously one-use only, see if you can't replace it with just a static method. Or several static methods.

Comment: Your code is fine for the general case, what you want is convenience method for the case of single values. Either add a constructor or static factory method to `Writer` that takes a single string and handles the messing about, e.g. something like `static void write(T value, Mapper<T, E> mapper, ...) { List<T> list = List.of(value); Writer w = new Writer(list.iterator(), str -> Collections.singletonList(str); ... }`